# Итераторы Java, списки Set HashSet Map HashMap Объясните конструкцию на вашем примере пожалуйста

Tags: java, итераторы

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Set set = new HashSet();
    set.add("Mama");
    set.add("Mila");
    set.add("Ramu");

    for (String text : set)   //Поясните в полной форме что означает это строчка //каждый ее символ
    {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во многих (если не во всех) языках программирования есть `foreach` - компактная форма цикла `for`, используемая в тех случаях, когда нужно обработать каждый элемент массива или чего-то ещё (в случае языка Java - каждый элемент объекта класса, имплементирующего интерфейс `Iterable`). Обычные массивы (`int[]`, `String[]`, `MyClass[]`) входят в это число.

Вот пример:

```
// Объявляем и инициализируем массив
int[] numbers = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// Проходимся по каждому элементу массива
for (int number : numbers) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

На экран будет выведено:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Если смотреть посимвольно на строку `for (int number : numbers)`:

```
for (      // сначала мы показываем, что хотим работать с циклом `for`,  
int        // объявляем тип итератора - в нашем случае это `int` (как и массив)
number     // пишем имя переменной, которая выступит итератором 
           // каждый раз она будет возвращать следующий элемент массива 
           // (и, значит, само собой разумеется, что она должна быть того 
           // же типа, какого и элементы массива)
: numbers) // а двоеточие и следом объект класса,
           // имплементирующего интерфейс `Iterable` говорит о том, 
           // что мы хотим пробежаться по всем элементам этого массива/листа/сета.
```

Подобная запись аналогична следующей:

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    int number = numbers[i];
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

В сетах, мапах/хешмапах и прочем, по понятным причинам, пробежаться по всем элементам не получится с помощью индексов, но сеты тоже имплементируют интерфейс `Iterable`, а список ключей и значений в мапах тоже сет.

Если рассмотреть пример с сетом:

```
// Объявляем и инициализируем наш сет
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();

// Добавляем в него элементы
stringSet.add("string_0");
stringSet.add("string_1");
stringSet.add("string_2");
stringSet.add("string_3");
stringSet.add("string_4");

// И теперь пробегаемся
// по каждому элементу сета
Iterator<String> iterator = stringSet.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String element = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Таким образом мы используем итератор, но эта же конструкция может быть проще:

```
// И теперь пробегаемся
// по каждому элементу сета
for (String element : stringSet) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

С интерфейсом `List` (а, соответствено, с `ArrayList` и прочими) всё также, как и с `Set`.

В случае с `Map`, `HashMap` и прочими, сначала определяете, по какому списку вам нужно пробежаться, а потом уже использовать тот же `foreach`.

Вот пример:

```
// Наша мап
Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

// Добавляем в нее элементы
hashMap.put("key_0", 0);
hashMap.put("key_1", 1);
hashMap.put("key_2", 2);
hashMap.put("key_3", 3);
hashMap.put("key_4", 4);

// В этом сете будут все ключи
Set<String> keys = hashMap.keySet();

// В этом списке будут все значения
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.values());

// Выводим все ключи на экран
System.out.println("Ключи:");
for (String key : keys) {
    System.out.println(key);
}

// Выводим все значения на экран
System.out.println("\nЗначения:");
for (Integer value : values) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

На экран будет выведено:

```
Ключи:
key_3
key_2
key_1
key_0
key_4

Значения:
3
2
1
0
4
```